# If operator, short circuiting, and null objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, short-circuiting

I'm having an issue in which the short circuiting [`If` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does not seem to be short circuiting.  Perhaps you all could help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly.  Or perhaps my conception of short circuiting is incorrect.

See below:

```
row.Item("v_total") = selectedForecastRow(0).Item("f_total") - _
           If(useZero, 0, CDbl(selectedActualRow(0).Item("a_total").ToString()))
```

In this example, selectedActualRow is `null`.  However, `useZero` is true, so I would assume that `If` would evaluate `useZero` as true and return 0, without evaluating `selectedActualRow` at all.

I was trying to use `If` to avoid writing a bunch of `If-Else` statements and keep my code more clean and concise, but if `If` can't perform this evaluation (due to the `null` third argument) then I guess I will choose another route.

Comment: Your understanding of `If()` is correct.  The third parameter will NOT be evaluated if "useZero" is true.  The problem is elsewhere, possibly in the first half of the equation before the minus sign?

Comment: I should have added that this code is inside a conditional  `If selectedForecastRow.Length > 0` so that row item has a value.  `row.Item("v_total")` has a value as well.

Comment: I suggest to start the debugger and check the real situation when the problem arises. I have replaced your rows with simple double and Nothing vars and there is no problem with the conditional evaluation of the expression

Comment: Agreed.  The Debugger is your friend...we won't be able to solve this problem from behind our keyboards.

Comment: Sorry guys. I thought I fundamentally didn't understand how short circuiting worked.  I removed the CDbl() method from the false argument and the code ran successfully.